# Installing luabind on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, lua

So I've been looking on the internet for a moment and found nearly no tutorial, or good instructions on how to install luabind. I found that I need to have boost and lua 5.xx installed to install it; I've already installed lua 5.3.1 ( which definitly works ), and installed boost like this : 
    `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` and checked it : it is in /usr/include/boost ;

Saw I installed those 2 libraries required. The Question would be how can I install luabind ? Are there any packages, or things like this ? Can any one give me some command line instructions so I can install it easily ?
PS : I checked the official documentation, but for some reason it did not work.

Comment: *but for some reason it did not work*: what exactly did not work? How exactly did it fail?

Comment: In Ubuntu, luabind is available from the repos:   apt-cache search luabind, 
libluabind-dbg - luabind c++ binding for lua: unstripped binaries, 
libluabind-dev - luabind c++ binding for lua: static library and headers,
libluabind-doc - luabind c++ binding for lua: documentation files,
libluabind-examples - luabind c++ binding for lua: example files,
libluabind0.9.1 - luabind c++ binding for lua: runtime library

Comment: I wrote : mkdir build; cd build;  cmake ..; make -> it could not recognize som lua functions

Comment: 2) Ok, so I wrote  sudo apt-get install libluabind-dev; it installed the static libraries; so now what argument should I pass to the linker ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libluabind-dev
```

*libluabind-dev* -- luabind c++ binding for lua: static library and headers
Luabind is a library that helps you create bindings between C++ and Lua. It has the ability to expose functions and classes, written in C++, to Lua. It will also supply the functionality to define classes in lua and let them derive from other lua classes or C++ classes. Lua classes can override virtual functions from their C++ baseclasses.

Comment: Ok, Thanks :) I did it; but what arguments should I pass to the linker ? ( for lua, I passed -lua -ldl )

Comment: Found it : -lluabind